# Strange date parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm loading some dates comming from my database into a HTML table in a string format. The string looks like `31-AUG-13` I'm parsing this string into a date object using the below code:

```
var paymentDate = $(this).find('td.paymentDate').text();
var test = $.datepicker.parseDate('d-M-y', paymentDate);
```

Everything is ok so far and I'm getting this date object: `Date {Sat Aug 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)}` But once the year is bigger than 2023. In my case `31-JAN-24` and so on it is turning to 1924 and not 2024, so I'm getting these date objects:

```
Date {Thu Jan 31 1924 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Daylight Time)}
Date {Fri Feb 29 1924 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Daylight Time)}
Date {Mon Mar 31 1924 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)}
Date {Wed Apr 30 1924 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)}
```

And so on. My question is regarding this strange issue. Is there a way to declare the year range and why it is going back to 1900 in the case when the year is bigger than 2023?

Comment: If it's a 2-digit year, shouldn't your pattern say `yy`?

Comment: `The problem affects all software and systems that both store system time as a signed 32-bit integer` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Why you can't load dates like 31-JAN-2024?

Comment: because it is stored into an oracle database liek that. Will `31-JAN-2024` solve the problem? I may try to convert it and return it liek taht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This teaches a lesson always use year in full format same was case with y2k problem. Convert date from database in to yyyy format then use it.

Comment: A real lesson! Thanks for your answer! I fixed it. :)